# Download wilink8 build script

Tags: git, shell, github

Sir,
      Actually i am using Virtual machine and runing ubuntu on this . Now for mine development i am trying to download somw build script using the command "git clone git//git.ti.com/wilink8-wlan/build-utilities.git" but i got the error 
    fatal error:unable to connect git.ti.com:
    git.ti.com[0: 198:47.29.151] error = conection refused

```
Could you please help me to solve this error step by step. I am working on Ubuntu machine.In mine college network some proxy server is running.
```

Answer (score -1):

First, telnet your proxy server and port from terminal as below;

```
telnet proxy.server.com 80
```

if telnet works, run as below;

```
git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@proxyserver:proxyport
```

if telnet not work, you should fix virtual machine network.

Comment: Sir i am able to connect to proxy server via telent.The one thing that i am not getting is that in this command : git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@proxyserver:proxyport   what i need to write at http.proxy and what i need to write at userand what i need to write at password.